# What does it mean when too much formality can appear menacing?

Tags: word-choice, tone

What does it mean when too much formality can appear menacing?

Consider the responses when one asks for a lemon:

> "Do you have any lemons in your fridge?"

- "No, sorry"
- "Nah"
- "No, I don't think so."
- "Nope."
- "Why? Do you need one?"

These responses seem normal or even friendly for some reason. Yet, if I ask,

> "Do you have any lemons in your fridge?"

and the response is

- **"No."**
- **"No, I don't."**
- **"Why?"**

These sentences seem different in tone. Something about their length makes them seem much more hostile. Is there a name for what I'm talking about?

Comment: They are more [*curt*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/curt) than the first set of responses.

Comment: The wiki on [politeness theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politeness_theory#Politeness_strategies) might be an interesting read for you. Longer responses might be indicative of attempts to mitigate face-threatening acts.

Comment: This question might be good for Writers.SE. My take on it is that overformality implies that you are suspending or ending a previously close relationship. Emotionally speaking, you are (or are threatening to) break it off by talking to the person not as a close friend, but as a stranger. The person being addressed is likely to feel hurt or angry because something of value to them is threatened.

Comment: @Cameron: 'face-threatening'? Is that the opposite of 'face-saving'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "extended" responses are [hedges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedge_%28linguistics%29) *- a mitigating device used to lessen the impact of an utterance*.

Hedges are so common in the context of a (disappointingly) negative reply that failure to use one isn't just "neutral" - it can actually seem hostile.